# pragmatically which character use to split the string

Tags: c#

I have a string like this:  "10+2 "

```
         char[] a = new char[] { '+', '-' };     
         string[] un = txtdiscout.Text.ToString().Split(a);   
         string str1 = un[0];  //value show 10 
         string str2 = un[1];  //value show 2
```

Basically, I can clearly see and  understand that the string is split by '+' character.
Is there a way to determine which character is used to split the string?

Comment: You wont a "ready to use" calculus on a split function ? Well make your custom parse of your string and collect the informations you need.

Comment: If you mean you want a result like ["10","+","2"] have alokk ar Regex.Split

Comment: It's hard to generalise from one example. What format are your other strings?

Comment: What happens with a string like "a+b;c-d;e*f;"?

Comment: With enough cases, most repeated character is probably the separator.

Answer (score 0):

There are several string calculator TDD samples. Here is my simple case using NUnit.

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestHarnessLite
    {

    [TestCase("add", "5+10", ArithmeticOperation.Addition, 15.0d)]
    [TestCase("subtract", "5-10", ArithmeticOperation.Subtraction, -5.0d)]
    [TestCase("multiply", "5*10", ArithmeticOperation.Multiplication, 50.0d)]
    [TestCase("divide", "10/5", ArithmeticOperation.Division, 2.0d)]
    public void SomeTest(string scenario, string textInput, ArithmeticOperation expectedOperation, double expectedValue)
    {
        //arrange
        var math = new SimpleExpressionCalculator();

        //act
        var actual = math.Calculate(textInput);
        var actualOperator = math.Operation;

        //assert
        Assert.That(actualOperator, Is.EqualTo(expectedOperation));
        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expectedValue), scenario);
    }

}

    public enum ArithmeticOperation
    {
        Unknown,
        Addition,
        Subtraction,
        Multiplication,
        Division
    }

public class SimpleExpressionCalculator
{
    public ArithmeticOperation Operation { get;set;}

    public double Calculate(string text)
    {
        var parsedValues = Parse(text);
        switch (parsedValues.Item2)
        {
            case "+":
                Operation = ArithmeticOperation.Addition;
                return parsedValues.Item1 + parsedValues.Item3;
            case "-":
                Operation = ArithmeticOperation.Subtraction;
                return parsedValues.Item1 - parsedValues.Item3;
            case "*":
                Operation = ArithmeticOperation.Multiplication;
                return parsedValues.Item1 * parsedValues.Item3;
            case "/":
                Operation = ArithmeticOperation.Division;
                if (parsedValues.Item3 == 0)
                    throw new DivideByZeroException("Can't divide by 0");
                return (parsedValues.Item1 *(1.0d)) / ((1.0d)*parsedValues.Item3);
        }
        return 0.0;
    }


    public Tuple<int,string,int> Parse(string input)
    {
        var groups = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+|[+-/*]+");
        if (groups.Count != 3)
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid input");
        int operand1 = int.Parse(groups[0].Value);
        string oper = groups[1].Value.Trim();
        int operand2 = int.Parse(groups[2].Value);
        return new Tuple<int, string, int>(operand1, oper, operand2);
    }

}
```